# Communicate with iDevice via C?

Tags: iphone, c, driver

I have seen this being done by the jailbreaking program, Spirit. I would just like to return simple information like the what kind of iDevice (like iPhone 3G, iPod touch 3G, iPad). Would this be very hard to do, or something kind of simple. (Such as: idevice_t *device; device->version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the `UIDevice` class. Among other info, it provides model info (iPod/iPhone/iPad, though not specific models) and the OS version.